# How can I pass parameter through URL to Facebook instant game app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

My facebook instant game app which have following url: https://www.facebook.com/instantgames/279246242904501/

When I hit the above game URL, Facebook website load the actual game inside iframe. I just want to pass URL parameter to my game app which I could receive using JavaScript inside my game code.

Can this be possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use link contexts. This is a currently undocumented feature, but if you navigate to `fb.gg/play/{your_game}/{ref}` you will end up in a unique context based on the value of *ref*. You can then use `context.getID()` to determine which context you are in.

Note, this can't be used to pass arbitrary date into the game because there's no way to read the string value of *ref*. There is currently no mechanism by which it is possible to do that.